# "Find Nearest" process for mobile device webapp?

Tags: javascript, mobile, geolocation, gps

Looking to implement a "Find Nearest" process for a mobile web application that will auto select the closest match of an item in a dropdown list in a form based on the user's current location.

Assuming we have the lat/long for each element of our list, and the persons location from the mobile device, what is the best method to locate the closest item?  We will have approx 150-200 possible items and want the one closest to the user so we can set it as the default.

Is there a means to efficiently do this in JS or would it be better suited to server side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a loop to calculate distance and henceforth, the closest. Use the Haversine formula:

```
var R = 6371; // km
var dLat = (lat2-lat1).toRad();
var dLon = (lon2-lon1).toRad(); 
var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
        Math.cos(lat1.toRad()) * Math.cos(lat2.toRad()) * 
        Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2); 
var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
var distance = R * c;
```

Better run your own benchmarks to find out if it would be better to do this server-side or client-side.

Comment: Thanks.  On a related approach, is there a means to possibly do this all via SQL Server TSQL?  So that we could create a webservice to accept a lat/long and then return the ID of the closest item?

Comment: You can certainly use `CREATE FUNCTION` for computing distance and invoke that function in your queries.

Comment: Thanks again. Managed to find the following and tailored it to our needs:  DECLARE @LATITUDE AS FLOAT
DECLARE @LONGITUDE AS FLOAT

SET @LATITUDE = 46.2102496001872
SET @LONGITUDE = -62.7978515625

SELECT TOP 1 ID, CoordName
 FROM (Select ID, CoordName, Lat, Long 
        From Coords) A
ORDER BY acos(sin(@Latitude/57.295779513082323) 
                * sin(Lat/57.295779513082323) 
        + cos(@Latitude/57.295779513082323) 
                * cos(Lat/57.295779513082323) 
                * cos(Long/57.295779513082323 - @Longitude/57.295779513082323))

Comment: You might want to define that as a TSQL function instead of repeating that formula everytime you compose a query string

Comment: I'm not sure how accurate your formula is but take a look at how Haversine is implemented in various languages: http://www.codecodex.com/wiki/Calculate_Distance_Between_Two_Points_on_a_Globe. And here's a TSQL function: http://jon.shoberg.net/2009/03/haversine-distance-in-miles-with-tsql-latitude-longitude/. Also here: http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=81360